# C# duplicate in listview

Tags: c#

So i've been writing a program to help me monitor a few things at work, I have them writing to a .txt file but when there is a file present in the directory i am monitoring it will keep writing the file to this txt file, for exmaple

```
New Text Document.txt - POA Submitted Directory - Current Time: 11:40:15 AM 1/9/2017 | Time Received: 1/9/2017 11:21:16 AM
New Text Document.txt - POA Directory - Current Time: 11:40:25 AM 1/9/2017 | Time Received: 1/9/2017 11:21:16 AM
New Text Document.txt - MTM Directory - Current Time: 12:48:28 PM 1/9/2017 | Time Received: 1/9/2017 11:21:16 AM
New Text Document.txt - MTM Directory - Current Time: 12:49:08 PM 1/9/2017 | Time Received: 1/9/2017 11:21:16 AM
New Text Document.txt - MTM Directory - Current Time: 12:49:18 PM 1/9/2017 | Time Received: 1/9/2017 11:21:16 AM
```

How should I keep this from repeating?

Here is my method for getting the directory listing

```
private void POACheck(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView2.Items.Clear();
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("Z:/FTPRoot/PDCUpload/POA");
    foreach (System.IO.FileInfo f in dir.GetFiles("*.*"))
    {
        FlashWindow(this.Handle, true);
        ListViewItem lSingleItem = listView2.Items.Add(f.Name);
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
        new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\sisson.chad\Desktop\POA-MTM.txt", true))
        {
            file.WriteLine(f.Name + " - POA Directory - Current Time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt") + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyy") + " | Time Received: " + f.LastWriteTime);
        }

    }
}
```

ALL help is appreciated, sorry I'm new to C# and I'm learning still.

Comment: Opps, sorry, are my tags good now?

Comment: One way would be to maintain a list of which elements have already been written and write only new ones.  Please read [ask] and also take the [tour]

Comment: StreamWriter parameter 'true' is appending instead of creating a new file.

Comment: @jdweng I need it to write to the same .txt file, i need it to not write the same line 5 times

Comment: Chad, did you tested your file listing snippet (the core of the event barring  ListView and FlashWindow calls ) outside the event and worked right, correct? I would try using async-await techniques to implement this event, make it return a Task and figure out which part of the snippet requires await.

Comment: Open the write file before the 'foreach' loop instead of inside the foreach loop.

Comment: Yes the snippet works correctly @fernandosoteras

Comment: Dont delete your text when solved

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to C#.  And also, to `List<T>`:

```
      private void POACheck(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listView2.Items.Clear();
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("Z:/FTPRoot/PDCUpload/POA");            
            var Names = new List<string>();
            foreach (System.IO.FileInfo f in dir.GetFiles("*.*"))
            {
               if(Names.IndexOf(f.Name) == -1) //-1 result from IndexOf means it's not there.
                {
                  FlashWindow(this.Handle, true);
                  ListViewItem lSingleItem = listView2.Items.Add(f.Name);
                  using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
                  new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\sisson.chad\Desktop\POA-MTM.txt", true))
                  {

                       file.WriteLine(f.Name + " - POA Directory - Current Time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt") + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyy") + " | Time Received: " + f.LastWriteTime);
                       Names.Add(f.Name);
                  }
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: New Text Document.txt - POA Directory - Current Time: 2:12:08 PM 1/9/2017 | Time Received: 1/9/2017 11:21:16 AM
New Text Document.txt - POA Directory - Current Time: 2:12:18 PM 1/9/2017 | Time Received: 1/9/2017 11:21:16 AM
New Text Document.txt - POA Directory - Current Time: 2:12:28 PM 1/9/2017 | Time Received: 1/9/2017 11:21:16 AM

Comment: This is still writing the same file, thank you for the attempt tho!